# Adding value to a new column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have added a new column as "DateOrder" to my existing table called "orders" and I need to add (insert) data to the new column.

The only way I have found is using the "Update, Set, Where" syntax, however, it forces me to add values each by repeating the syntax.

I would appreciate if you help me how I can insert all my values at once.

Comment: Hello Mahyar : what data do you want to put in the new column ? Like the current date for every row, or something more specific or depending on the content of each row ?

Comment: it would be "integer" e.g. 23052018

Comment: so, `23052018` for all rows ?

Comment: I have 4 rows. and I have three more integers just similar what I mentioned above. ( i am just practicing)

Comment: If you are creating a column to store a date, use datatype `DATE` or `DATETIME`, not `INT`, which is to store integer numbers. Also, you would need to explain better what you expect the new column to be populated with in existing rows.

Comment: I will drop the column and try with DATE or DATETIME. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, while creating the new column set a default value to it. And see if it has any binding with others. Then after you can directly insert new values to new records and update previous records just by update.

Answer (score 1):

Four rows only? Then use `CASE WHEN` in the `SET` clause:

```
update orders
set dateorder =
(
  case id
    when 1 then date '2018-10-13'
    when 2 then date '2017-08-24'
    when 3 then date '2019-01-11'
    when 4 then date '2018-02-02'
  end
);
```

Don't store dates as integers. Store them as dates as shown.